# How do I access the standard controller without passing the ID parameter in the URL

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardcontroller

How can I use the standard controller to access fields on a record in a visualforce page without passing the ID in the URL?

**Example:** Instead of "https://c.xxx.visual.force.com/apex/abc?id=a0890010008dQTE", I want to use "https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/tabbed".

Comment: whats the use case here? is it just asthetics? security?

Comment: simply want to display record details from an ID.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if you are using a StandardController, you can overload the internal `id` in an extension:

```
public with sharing class AbcExtension {

    public AbcExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        //this will work just as if you'd handed it in as part of the url 
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', 'a0890010008dQTE');
    }
}
```

Alternately you can use another parameter (such as name) to pass in the url

```
public with sharing class AbcExtension {

    public AbcExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        // get the parameter from the url
        String otherParameter = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('otherParameter');

        // query the object
        Abc__c theObject = [SELECT ID, .... FROM Abc__c WHERE Some_Field__c = :otherParameter LIMIT 1];

        // You'll need to add in some error handling code..

        // this will set the Id, so now you can use the standard controller and just reference fields on the page
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', theObject.Id);
    }
}
```

And in your page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Abc__c" extensions="AbcExtension" />
```

Comment: then won't this code only work for a single record- what ever that ID is? anyway to make it more scalable?

Comment: Yep. I suspect @MnZ is using it for a Site or such and just wants a clean URL.

Comment: yes @user320, you are right. But I will also want to try what nivyaj has suggested. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Sure, you can use the [Site.UrlRewriter](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm) interface to clean them up. Maybe clarify in a separate question?

Comment: oh that's a handy part of the api.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @user320 your suggestion is indeed very handy :)